# Symfony 2.5.6 error InvalidArgumentException: The service definition "event_dispatcher" does not exist

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to build my first Compiler Pass in Symfony 2. For now, I'm just trying to get the core event_dispatcher service from FrameWorkBundle inside a SampleBundle, but I get this error :

```
error InvalidArgumentException: The service definition "event_dispatcher" does not exist.
```

Here is the code for my compiler :

```
<?php
namespace Me\SampleBunlde\DependencyInjection\Compiler;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;

class RegisterListenersPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('event_dispatcher');
    }
}
?>
```

I'm a bit surprised since I'm following step by step a professionnal Symfony book who assures me that I will find this service with that id.

I've done some researches about that, and I discovered that only the debug.event_dispatcher service was avaible. Then I checked for aliases and saw that there was a private Alias named 'event_dispatcher' pointing to debug.event_dispatcher. So I'm really confused about all that. And I'm wondering :

- Why is the Alias private ? Do I need to set him Public or is it the wrong way ?
- Why Symfony does not automatically interprets my event_dispatcher call ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `findDefinition()` instead of `getDefinition()`. `findDefinition` also looks for aliases.